# ADB-client stops working when root is turned on

Tags: cyanogenmod, adb, root-access, custom-roms

Very strange - I've Cyanogenmod rooted device and cannot use the adb-client from computer when rooting is turned on. In other words  i have to go to developer settings, turn off rooting - then I can access the device from the computer.

The problem i need to be able to connect computer with the device in rooted mood cince i've an nandroid there to push back to clockworkmod on the device.

What could the reason be adb from computer no longer work when root is turned on?
I dont get it!

And another question - whats the alternatives if I want to copy a rom-image from computer back to the device?

thanks in advance

Comment: Which CM version and build is it and for which device? See if *adb root* works.

Comment: @Firelord CM version: 6.0.4.6 ; Kernel-version: 3.0.31-ArchiKernel-CM-gd13f4d1root@ArchiDroid#1.;  Samsung Galaxy SIII i9300

Comment: is adb-daemon residing in kernel or userspace? just curious